# Tabulator run validator after running mutator

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

I have a column in tabulator table like below -

```
{title: "Media", field: "ttend_external_code_1", editor: "input", 
 validator:["regex:^[0-9]{0,2}$", "unique"], mutatorEdit:zero_padding, mutatorEditParams:{length_with_pad:2}}
```

The mutator function which padds 0 at the front of the input number

```
function zero_padding(value, data, type, params, component) {
    return value.padStart(params.length_with_pad, '0');
}
```

Problem is the field should contain unique values as the validator. It works if 2 digit number is input into the cell. But if i enter single digit or no digit number it enters the 0 padded number even if it is not unique, for whatever reason the unique validation is not working. Is there a work around? I want to catch invalid input after the mutator data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Validation happens before the mutator is run which is why you are running into issues.

data mutation is only performed after a value has passed validation.

You would need to write a [Custom Validation Function](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/validate#func-custom) to handle this specific usage case

Comment: I already have several custom validation functions. 
I solved it just by performing the actual validation after padding values inside the validator functions, and then performing validations.